# Trigger function on form button submit

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a form with a number of text inputs and a submit button at the end. On submit I'd like to trigger a function and I'm having difficulty.

The form is below and I have tried the following:

```
$('#contactForm input.btn_submit').click(function(event){ // function here

$('#contactForm input.btn_submit').click(function(event){ // function here

$('#contactForm.report_row.input.btn_submit').click(function(event){ // function here
```

But with no luck.

Here is the form:

```
<form action="https://example.com/index.php/contact" method="post" id="contactForm" name="contactForm">
    <input type="hidden" />

    <div class="report_row">
        <strong>Your Name:</strong><br />
        <input type="text" id="contact_name" name="contact_name" value=""  class="text" />              </div>
    <div class="report_row">
        <strong>Your Email Address:</strong><br />
        <input type="text" id="contact_email" name="contact_email" value=""  class="text" />                </div>
    <div class="report_row">
        <strong>Your Phone Number:</strong><br />
        <input type="text" id="contact_phone" name="contact_phone" value=""  class="text" />                </div>
    <div class="report_row">
        <strong>Message Subject:</strong><br />
        <input type="text" id="contact_subject" name="contact_subject" value=""  class="text" />                </div>                              
    <div class="report_row">
        <strong>Message:</strong><br />
        <textarea id="contact_message" name="contact_message"  rows="4" cols="40" class="textarea long" ></textarea>                </div>      
    <div class="report_row">
        <strong>Security Code:</strong><br />
        20 + 9 = <br />
        <input type="text" id="captcha" name="captcha" value=""  class="text" />                </div>
    <div class="report_row">
        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Send Message" class="btn_submit" />
    </div>
</form>
```

How would I trigger a function on someone clicking the submit button at the end?

Comment: Are you including jQuery? Did you wrap your jQuery in a document ready call?

Comment: Not sure if this is a typo in your question , but selectors doesn't seems to have space between them.. i.e `$('#contactForm .report_row input.btn_submit')` or just simply `$('#contactForm').find('.btn_submit').`

Comment: But you can try this `$('#contactForm.btn_submit')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will be triggered anytime the form is submitted:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#contactForm').submit(function() { 
        //... your code here
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Not clear what you mean with "*I'm having difficulty*".

It might be that you don't stop the form submission so you can run your function. In that case you need to use `.preventDefault()`. I suggest you also wrap your function in a ready function so your code will run when the page has loaded all html.

like:

```
$('#contactForm input.btn_submit').click(function(event){ 
    event.preventDefault();
    // rest of code
    alert('Working!');
});
```

**Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cw6GV/)**

Answer (score 1):

what about

```
$('form').submit(function(){// ...
                                    });
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can try doing something like this:

```
$('#contactForm').submit(function() {

});
```

or

```
$('#contactForm').on('submit', function() {

});
```